# Какую роль играет types импорттированный из telebot?

Tags: python, telebot

Начал значит я учить как создавать ботов в telegram, и в ресурсе где я учу не уточняется многие термины связанные с telebot было бы круто если бы кто-то скинул сайт где все подробно расписано, так как я чайник, а основной  вопрос это - "Какую роль играет types импорттированный из telebot?"

Answer (score 1):

Открыл репозиторий библиотеки и там есть документация: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#types

> All types are defined in types.py. They are all completely in line
> with the [Telegram API's definition of the types](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-types), except for the
> Message's from field, which is renamed to from_user (because from is a
> Python reserved token). Thus, attributes such as message_id can be
> accessed directly with message.message_id. Note that message.chat can
> be either an instance of User or GroupChat (see [How can I distinguish
> a User and a GroupChat in message.chat?](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#how-can-i-distinguish-a-user-and-a-groupchat-in-messagechat)).
>
> The Message object also has a content_typeattribute, which defines the
> type of the Message. content_type can be one of the following strings:
> text, audio, document, photo, sticker, video, video_note, voice,
> location, contact, new_chat_members, left_chat_member, new_chat_title,
> new_chat_photo, delete_chat_photo, group_chat_created,
> supergroup_chat_created, channel_chat_created, migrate_to_chat_id,
> migrate_from_chat_id, pinned_message.
>
> You can use some types in one function. Example:
>
> content_types=["text", "sticker", "pinned_message", "photo", "audio"]

Comment: Там же ведь вовсе и не написано какую роль играет types, к примеру здесь : types.InlineKeyboardButton()

Comment: `They are all completely in line with the Telegram API's definition of the types`, т.е. все типы из types.py соответствуют типам из API телеграмма